# Is "Jai Shri Krishn" (जय श्री कृष्ण ) a valid sanskrit phrase?

Tags: krishna, sanskrit

Is जय श्री कृष्ण (Jai Shri Krishna) a valid sanskrit phrase ?
Or the correct phrase should be something like - जयतु श्री कृष्ण: (Jaytu Shri Krishnah)

I am not very well versed in sanskrit.

Also what is the exact meaning of the जय श्री कृष्ण ? Does it convey proper meaning ?

I know It is souning pendantic but I just want to know the meanings of things.
In my opinion chanting Jai Shri Krishna should also be fine as most people do it this way. Also in जय श्री कृष्ण all words are of Sanskrit anyway.
But I just wanted to know the meaning.

Comment: Jai shri krishna is addressing him directly. Win oh Krishna. Jayatu krishnah is third person. May Krishna win. May Krishna be victorious.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "VedVyas" vs "Veda Vyasa" argument.  HSE is is one place where the Hindi form  doesn't usually replace the Sanskrit form.  There is a short "a" sound at the end of many Sanskrit words ("Rama","Krishna","Veda") which have tatsama Hindi words derived from them "Ram","Krishn","Ved" without the ending "a".

"Jai" is Hindi and "Jaya" is Sanskrit.

"Jaya Shri Krishna" is Sanskrit.  literally, it is "ordering" Krishna to be victorious - but its intended meaning is "victory unto you, Krishna"

Comment: Can't Jai also be a Sanskrit word ? After all it is sanskrit word , even if it is root word. 
Also Isn't there a  Sanskrit song in which it is recited - Jai Jai Jai Mahisasur Mardini ?

Comment: If you are a native speaker of a North Indian language, you would hear it that way.  But in Sanskrit it is "jaya jaya he Mahishasura mardini.",   "jai" is not a Sanskrit word.  the verb root is "ji". @river